# SSL Not being served by Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I am running multiple virtual hosts on my apache and I want one virtual host to server ssl.

I have followed the [instructions given to me](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1203&nav=0,1) from where I purchased my certificate.

Whenever I visit my site using https, I get an "Unable to connect error" in Firefox.

My ssl.conf which is included by httpd.conf looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/path/to/dir"
ServerName *.xxx.xxx.com
ServerAlias *.xxx.xxx.com
Alias /path "/var/www/html/development/path/to/somewhere/else"

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt/STAR_xxx_xxx_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/crt/private.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/STAR_xxx_xxx_com.ca-bundle

<Directory "/var/www/html/path/to/dir">
  Order Deny,Allow 
  Allow from all
  Options -Indexes
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

What else can I do to solve this?

EDIT Some other thoughts:

1. I have read that my apache has to be compiled somehow with SSL. Is this an issue?
2. In some configurations the Listen 443 in enclosed in  tags. Is this also an issue?

When I do a lsof -I :443 I get a

> COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME

```
httpd   8872   root    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8874 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8875 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8876 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8877 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8878 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8879 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8880 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8881 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8893 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8894 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   8895 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   9067 apache    5u  IPv6 78180368       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

I think prolly not waht I expected since I only want one virtual host to listen to 443. Or is this correct?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your configuration, and any errors that Apache puts in its logs during the service's start.

Comment: Check whether the server is actually listening on port 443 or not. (With a 'netstat' or similar command.) That will split the problem space in half.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz done

Comment: @Jeune: What was the result? Was the server listening on port 443 or not?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz updated my post now

Comment: @Jeune: That's correct. Each apache process has inherited the a copy of the descriptor. So the server is listening. My guess would be firewall issue.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz From my end or the server's end? I can access other https sites just fine.

Comment: @Jeune Is the error you're having from Apache or from your browser?

Comment: Also, may sound silly, but did you restart apache after making the changes?

Comment: No error in the apache logs but I can't access my site either from the browser.

Comment: @kobaltz yes of course I restarted apache

Comment: Are you able to ping on both 80 and 443? Remove the 443 from the NameVirtualHost and just use :80, Also make sure that the ssl mods are in your mods-enabled.

Comment: @kobaltz you can't ping a port but I tried nmap and it says both ports are open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve this problem by restarting the iptables

```
service iptables stop
service iptables start
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a line like this in your `httpd.conf`?

```
Listen 443
```

Comment: Yeah I do have that in the ssl.conf which is included by the httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating two different tags for http and https? Also, are you pointing to yoru certificates? Your location will vary from mine below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>


   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /var/cert/domain.net.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/cert/domain.key.nopass
   SSLCertificateChainFile /var/cert/gd_bundle_domain.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I do have those things too

Comment: Do I really need separate tags for http and https? Won't just https suffice?

Comment: I think that you would need the separate tags because one is declaring the SSLEngine and the locations for the certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You may have port 443 closed by your firewall. On Linux you can list rules by running `iptables -L`

Comment: I tried to scan ports using nmap and port 443 is open

Comment: You have tried to scan ports from localhost or some remote host?

Comment: I executed the command in the shell connected to my remote host via ssh.